What happens when an elephant charges at an immovable rod?
This is a question my D&D group has had for a while; what happens when an elephant charges at an immovable rod. Either the elephant will be able to overcome the rod's weight limit in the first instance, or the rod will penetrate the elephant's skin, at which point we need to figure out how far into the elephant the rod goes.
I'm looking for a step by step mathematical explanation to be able to calculate this as I've been really stumped on how the magic item interacts with real world physics and on other things like how to calculate if the rod penetrates the skin. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
To specify, I imagine the rod to be parallel with the ground at chest height of the elephant, with the elephant charging the rod at full speed so that it impacts at the end of the rod.
If you feel like doing the calculation with specific values I'll leave some relevant rulings here, otherwise just an explanation of what calculations should be done would be very helpful:

Immovable rod description: "This flat iron rod has a button on one end. You can use an action to press the button, which causes the rod to become magically fixed in place. Until you or another creature uses an action to push the button again, the rod doesn't move, even if it is defying gravity. The rod can hold up to 8,000 pounds of weight. More weight causes the rod to deactivate and fall. A creature can use an action to make a DC 30 Strength check, moving the fixed rod up to 10 feet on a success."
Immovable rod other: A general description of rods in the dmg states "A scepter or just a heavy cylinder, a magic rod is typically made of metal, wood, or bone. It's about 2 or 3 feet long, 1 inch thick, and 2 to 5 pounds." So to simplify we can say that the rod is a metal cylinder, 2.5 ft long, with a 1 inch diameter, and weighs 2lbs (the weight as per the immovable rod's description).
The Elephant: A 5e elephant has a speed of 40ft. Assuming it is dashing we can say it is moving at 80ft/6 seconds. Any other information that cannot be gleaned from the statblock such as mass or other can be taken as the average of an Asian elephant. Some values are hard to come by like stress and strain information for elephant skin, so sensible substitutes such as the info instead for unworked cow leather, which would likely be easier to find online can be used (please cite the source of any value you use that is not taken directly from 5e rulings).


What happens if an elephant charges into a cliff face? Why would this be different?

Why would you use physics?
Using real world physics in a case like this is both unnecessary and bound to fail.  It would be like trying to use real world physics to calculate how much damage a sword or mace blow does; there are already game abstractions that do that without referencing physics, so why would you try to insert calculations?
Within the game - force
The description of the rod says (emphases mine):

The rod can hold up to 8,000 pounds of weight. More weight causes the rod to deactivate and fall.

Notice that the limit to what the rod can support is not a generalized force, but specifically weight.  If the elephant were stepping on the rod, bringing its weight to bear, we might need to know its weight.  But if the elephant is charging the rod, the component of its weight that acts on the rod (the downward component of the impact force) is negligible.  By the definition of the rod, it is immovable from the force of impact.
Within the game - an attempt to move
The rod description continues:

A creature can use an action to make a DC 30 Strength check, moving the fixed rod up to 10 feet on a success.

This is the part of the rod description that is relevant.  If the elephant is attempting to move the rod, it must use an Action to do so.  The game rules work around the power of intentionality - there are many things that characters can accomplish when they try to, but cannot achieve by accident, even if the physics of the situation are identical.  Lateral impacts by themselves, no matter how powerful, do not move the rod at all; Actions have a chance to.
It doesn't matter whether it is charging, or dug in and pushing, or pulling with its trunk; the elephant gets a Strength check when it attempts to move the rod.  With a strength bonus of +6, the elephant will normally not be able to make a DC30 check, and so will be unable to move the rod unless some other factor modifies the roll.
Within the game - an attempt to damage
If the elephant is not attempting to move the rod, it might be attempting to damage it.  We know the elephant's capacity to damage; it has a 5 foot range gore attack with +8 to hit, and 3d8+6 piercing damage.  This does not require it to have moved.  If it is deliberately chest-butting the rod as you specify rather than using its tusks, that would be an unarmed attack for +8 to hit and 7 bludgeoning damage.  The elephant does have a special "trampling charge" attack, but this affects creatures, not objects.  For the rod, we use the DMG section on damaging objects (246); it has an AC of between 19 and 23 and hp between 3 and 18.  As a magic item, it is resistant to damage.
Normally, when a creature attempts to damage an object, the creature does not take damage in return.  If, for some reason, the elephant was charging the rod rather than standing next to it to attack, you might assign the elephant damage for the sake of verisimilitude.  It would be within the spirit of the rules to divide the damage the elephant did between itself and the rod, as the optional rules for falling onto a creature suggest, so that the rod would ultimately take (3d8 + 6) / 4 and the elephant would take (3d8 + 6) / 2.  If, for some reason (such as your striking visual of an elephant impaling itself), it was very important to consider that the elephant was receiving this damage in a small surface area (unlike falling), you might decide that the damage was assigned with an automatic critical, for a total of (6d8 + 6) / 2 to the elephant.
The 5e system is set up to have different effects occur depending on the intentions of the participants.  Situations like this can be run entirely within the rules, with no physics needed.

The rules don't say
The rules for an immovable rod don't specify what happens when a moving object strikes one. You'll have to ask your DM for a ruling. Remember, D&D is not a physics simulator. Many of the rules are abstractions to facilitate play rather than being excessively realistic.
If you want to calculate it
To find the amount of force an object exerts during a collision, you simply use this formula:
Force = mass * speed / time
Stopping time is the figure we don't have, so let's see how quickly the elephant would need to be stopped by the rod in order to break the rods weight limit. Solving for time we get:
Time = mass * speed / force
This means we can plug in your figures to get:
Time = 9000 lbs * 13.333 feet/second / 8000 lbs force
Time = 15 seconds
This means as long as the elephant is stopped within 15 seconds of collision (which I think is a fair assumption), it will break the weight limit.

Elephants can easily weigh enough for the rod to "deactivate and fall"
